# Loop through tuple and calculate percentage of a number

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I am trying to loop through the below `tuple` (`tuple1`), create a *total* from the integers (`b`), calculate a the *percentage* each value represents, and store it along with variable `a`, in a new variable (`a_percent`)

I have attempted the following:

```
tuple1 = [('Data1', 33), ('Data2', 52), ('Data3', 85)]

total = b
for a, b in tuple1:
    total += b
    y = b/total*100.0
    a_percent = a, y
```

My ***expected*** output for a_percent is e.g. for `Data1`: (`33/(33+52+85)*100`):

```
Data1, 19.4 ...   
Data2, 30.5 ...
Data3, 50
```

However, it appears as followed instead:

```
('Data1', 100.0)
('Data2', 0.0)
('Data3', 0.0)
```

Comment: where is x coming from?

Comment: @AriGold My mistake, `x` was meant to be `total`

Comment: and y "....y = b/y*100.0....",  and "total = b"?

Comment: sry but it still problematic, what mean "total = b"?

Comment: @AriGold Total add's the integers. That's fine. Nothing to change there. That would mean b/total*100.0 would be: `33/(33+52+85)*100` ?

Comment: No Sir, total = b is not correct, .......NameError: name 'b' is not defined, why? But its ok, go ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `b/y` when both are ints, resulting in integer division. It doesn't matter that you multiply by `100.0` afterwards. Either do `float(b)/y*100.0` or `b*100.0/y`.

Though this code doesn't do what you want it to, and you can't get the percent that each value is without two loops through. Instead, may I suggest

```
total = sum([t[1] for t in tuple1])
a_percent = [(t[0], float(t[1])/total) for t in tuple1]
```

Answer (score 2):

bit in a basic solution that you were trying. may help you in understanding this easily.

```
tuple1 = [('Data1', 33), ('Data2', 52), ('Data3', 85)]

total = 0
for a, b in tuple1:
    total += int(b)

for a,b in tuple1:
    y = float(int(b)) * 100 /total
    a_percent = a, y
    print a_percent
```

output:

```
('Data1', 19.41176470588235)
('Data2', 30.58823529411765)
('Data3', 50.0)
```

Comment: @AlexC. please do not make significant changes to this answer that would deviate from what this user is trying to convey.  That behaviour is not acceptable here on Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Comment: @rayryeng There is nothing that is deviates what I'm trying to convey. I found this answer the most useful, if anything.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, I implied his answer hasn't deviated from my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the `total` first and then loop over to calculate the percentages:

```
>>> tuple1 = [('Data1', 33), ('Data2', 52), ('Data3', 85)]
>>> total = sum(t[1] for t in tuple1)
>>> tuple_new = [(x, float(y) * 100 /total) for x, y in tuple1]
>>> tuple_new
[('Data1', 19.41176470588235), ('Data2', 30.58823529411765), ('Data3', 50.0)]
```

If you need to you can include the actual count in the tuple as well:

```
>>> [(x, y, float(y) * 100 /total) for x, y in tuple1]
[('Data1', 33, 19.41176470588235), ('Data2', 52, 30.58823529411765), ('Data3', 85, 50.0)]
```

Comment: in the for loop `t` is one tuple in the list e.g. `('Data1' 33)` and where elements in the tuple can be fetched using 0-index system so `t[0]` is `'Data'` and `t[1]` is `33`. So first we are getting the total by summing up the 1st element in all the tuples and then calculating the percentages in another loop. I assumed you understood this because the accepted answer also contains `t[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[y[1] for y in tuple1]
sum_tuple = sum([y[1] for y in tuple1])
[(y[0], (float(y[1])/sum_tuple)*100) for y in tuple1]
```

Output :

```
[('Data1', 19.411764705882355), ('Data2', 30.58823529411765), ('Data3', 50.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple answer (not yet tested)

```
total = 0
for data, value in tuple1:
      total += value     #get the total

for data,value in tuple1:
      print float(value) / total * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy application:

```
tuple1 = [('Data1', 33), ('Data2', 52), ('Data3', 85)]

total = (sum(t[1] for t in tuple1))
for a, b in tuple1:
    y = b * 100 / total
    a_percent = a, y
    print(a_percent)
```

Output:

```
('Data1', 19.41176470588235)
('Data2', 30.58823529411765)
('Data3', 50.0)
```